# Run class initializer for Core Data Manager in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Before you read take into consideration that I'm at really early stage of iOS developing :)
I have class SomeManager that manipulates data by Core Data framework in my iOS application. I created initializer for that Manager in such way:

```
class UserManager {
    private let appDelegate: AppDelegate
    private let context: NSManagedObjectContext

init() {
    self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    self.context = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Further I have some methods that perform that manipulation with User NSManagedObject class.

So I have 2 questions.
1. Is this way correct?
2. Where(in what stage) I should implement multithreading (by GCD) for my Manager? Should I do it in initializer or in Manager methods? Or in ViewController?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a few questions are going on here.  It's is hard to say what is "Correct", but there are some more or less architecturally sound solutions.

**Question 1**

**For simple cases:**

If you are going to be only reading from CoreData, or are doing very light weight writes (and maybe even don't mind the app UI freezing for a moment in worst case scenarios) making `context = persistentContainer.viewContext` can work fine (assuming `appDelegate.persistentContainer` was already created else where).

**For Enterprise Architectural cases:**

If you are looking into MVVM/MVP/VIPER, typically the CoreData specific code is in it's own class whose single responsibility is to manage how the Data goes in and comes out.  So that class would know what contexts to use when.  Usually writes will be in the background using the `persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask`, unless you need more control by making your own contexts.

**Question 2**

You should start using multithreading when you noice your UI is bogging down, or you have lots of writes (and bulk writes) happening.  The `persistentContainer` is great though, because you can throw stuff on the background and not worry about creating and managing the other threads yourself:

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask{ context in
   //do some stuff on a background thread
   let person = Person(context: context) //creating a person for example

   try! context.save() //this will save that Person to the database

   //returning to the UI Thread
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //tell the UI thread to do something
   }
}
```

Your manager looks like you are starting to separate your data layer from the view logic (a best practice), so I would definitely not create or use your contexts directly in the view controller, and keep your data layer separate.